# How to make a size slider in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I'm new to netlogo and i'm trying to make a slider that allows you to change the size of the turtles. 
so far i've made a slider called size-of-turtle
and in the code i tried putting:
"set size size-of-turtle"
but i just get an error message.
please help.

Comment: ``ask turtles [set size size-of-turtle]``

Comment: What is the error message that you get?  Are you putting your code inside a procedure, or are you running it from the Command Center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've made a slider with a global variable size-of-turtle. Do you have a procedure that will actually tell the turtles to do what you ask?

And yes, please show your error message. If you have a slider that nothing refers to, nothing will happen when you change the values on the slider. I suggest creating a turtle and running the code

```
ask turtles [set size sizeofturtle]
```

somewhere, preferably in a forever loop so that it is easy to see the change as you move the slider.